# c# anonymous type question

Tags: c#, language-features, anonymous-types

In the following code why are the variables c2 and c3 of a different anonymous type?

Thanks in advance for any advice and ... cheers !

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c1 = new Customer { Name = "Mark", Country = "USA" };

            var c2 = new { c1.Name, c1.Country };   //"<>f__AnonymousType0`2"
            var c3 = new { c1.Country, c1.Name };   //"<>f__AnonymousType1`2"
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you initialized their properties in different orders.

They'll only be compiled to the same anonymous type if you initialize them in the same order. From the MSDN docs on [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

> If two or more anonymous types in the same assembly have the same number and type of properties, in the same order, the compiler treats them as the same type.